# Getting parameter for a stored procedure inside another stored procedure.

Tags: sql, vb.net

This is probably more of a "best practices" question than a true code question.

I have a stored procedure to update a table, but needs a couple of values from another table.

the first two selects get the value from the table and then are used in the update statement.

The select statments:

```
 Select @iStatusDropDownValueID = iDropDownValueID
        From DropDownValue
        Inner Join DropDownValueType On DropDownValue.iDropDownValueTypeID = DropDownValueType.iDropDownValueTypeID
        Where DropDownValueType.vchDropDownValueTypeName = 'Status'
        AND DropDownValue.vchDropDownValueName = 'Scheduled'
        AND DropDownValue.tiRecordStatus = 1
        And DropDownValueType.tiRecordStatus = 1

 Select @iLastStatusDropDownValueID = iDropDownValueID
        From DropDownValue
        Inner Join DropDownValueType On DropDownValue.iDropDownValueTypeID = DropDownValueType.iDropDownValueTypeID
        Where DropDownValueType.vchDropDownValueTypeName = 'Status'
        AND DropDownValue.vchDropDownValueName = 'CriticalErrorOccurred'
        AND DropDownValue.tiRecordStatus = 1
        And DropDownValueType.tiRecordStatus = 1
```

The Update statement:

```
Update Schedule
    Set
        iStatusDropDownValueID = @iStatusDropDownValueID,
        iLastStatusDropDownValueID = @iLastStatusDropDownValueID,
        iCurrentLogID = @iCurrentLogID,
        dtNextDate = @dtNextDate,
        dtLastDate = @dtLastDate,
        iRetryCount = @iRetryCount,
        iFailedCount = @iFailedCount,
        iBusyRetryCount = @iBusyRetryCount,
        vchUpdateBy = @vchUpdateBy,
        dtUpdateDate = @dtLastDate
    WHERE
        iScheduleID = @iScheduleID
```

First, the values that are retrieved by the first two select statements are always the same. So they could be passed in by the code itself. I don't know that this will speed things up at all, just make the entire stored procedure better and easier to read.

Second, if the "Value Name" should change this store procedure will break (which is possible, but not often).

I am looking for any insight into the Best Practices for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I always declare my variables and don't use @vars.
@vars are like variants, they don't protect you against typos.
If you use explicitly declared variables, MySQL will warn you against typos and your vars will be typed making your intentions clearer and your code slightly faster.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE (IN a INTEGER) 
BEGIN
  DECLARE var1 INTEGER;
  DECLARE var2 INTEGER;
  DECLARE initialized_var INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

  SET var = 1;  //to just set a var.
  SELECT myfield INTO var2 FROM atable WHERE a <> atable.b ORDER BY b LIMIT 1;
  //Always use `limit 1` here.
  //use `select into ...order by .. limit 1` to make you queries repeatable.
  //The limit 1 also speeds up things a bit.
  //make sure to test SELECT INTO vars against `null`  
  IF var2 IS NULL THEN .....
```

If you need to use the outcome of one stored procedure, why not make a stored function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION pi RETURNS float
BEGIN
   RETURN 3.14;
END $$
```

Then you can just write a query like:

```
INSERT INTO atable (math_constants) VALUES (pi());
```

Comment: You have brought up a couple of things I didn't realize you could do. Which is great! The only issue I see with using a function is that if the name changes the function will still break.

Comment: @Andy, why would the function break?, just have it return `null` upon failure and test for that in your function.

Comment: You are right, they would not fail. I was thinking if the value changed for any reason. But in this case the value would never change only the dropdownname.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but if the values being retrieved are truly invariant, why pass them in *or* retrieve them at all?  You could simply hardcode them in.

I would tend toward doing so in this case, as it not only removes the overhead of the retrieval queries, but removes a potential point of failure (the "value name" change you mention in the question).

Comment: A failure is exactly what is happening. the code passes in a 0 value for these two values, then there is an additional condition statement to get the values if they are needed. The condition is not right so the values are always 0 causing a foreign key exception.